# Passing JSONified object to back-end in Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, django

Im trying to turn an Object created in js into JSON and then passed to my back-end in Django.

First I make a list of lists:

```
function get_account_info(){
    var account_list = [];
    $('.card').each(function(e){
        var account = [];
        account.push($(this).find('.name').val());
        account.push($(this).find('.username').val());
        account.push($(this).find('.password').val());

        if(account[0] != null){
            account_list.push(account);
        }
    })
    return account_list;
}
```

Then I try to post it:

```
var account_info_json = JSON.parse(get_account_info());
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/create_new_group/create_group/',
            data:{
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                account_info: account_info_json,
            } ,
            success:function(data){
                    if(data.status == 1){
                            //success!
                            console.log('Success!')
                    }
                    else if(data.status == 2){
                            //failed
                            console.log('Failed!')
                    }
            }
```

And this is what I get when I print(json.dumps(request.POST)) in my views.py

```
{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "token_data_is_here", "account_info": "[[\"1111111\",\"1111111\",\"1111111\"],[\"222222\",\"222222\",\"222222\"]]"}
```

I can only acces this data like a stirng, not JSON. How can I make it so I access it like JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all the data will be converted to string before it is sent, so when it comes to django you need to first convert string to json.

to convert from string to json:

```
import json
str = json.loads(json_data)
```

to obtain json from string:

```
import json
json_data = json.loads(str)
```

in your case you need to convert string to json before accessing it as a dictionary in python

hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

You have deserialize json string first:

```
import json
account_info = json.loads(request.POST['account_info'])
```